How many values of a group cocycle are required to know its cohomology class?
Suppose I have a finite group $G$, and a group cocycle $\varphi\in Z^n(G,U(1))$ (trivial action on $U(1)$) evaluated at $k$ distinct values of the inputs $g_1,...,g_n$. That is, I am given a set of values $\varphi(g_{1,1},...,g_{1,n}),...,\varphi(g_{k,1},...,g_{k,n})$. What is the minimal $k$ such that the cohomology class $[\varphi]$ can be determined uniquely?
As an example, I know that for $n=3,G=\mathbb{Z}_2$, if
$$
\varphi(g_1,g_2,g_3)=\nu(g_2,g_3)\nu(g_1g_2,g_3)\nu^{-1}(g_1,g_2g_3)\nu^{-1}(g_1,g_2)
$$
is a coboundary, then
$$\varphi(1,0,1)\varphi(1,1,1)=1$$
and the invariant above gives $-1$ for the nontrivial cocycle. So in that case $k=2$. However, if there is a generalization to that formula I am missing it.
The case I care about the most is $n=3, G=\mathbb{Z_m}$, but if there is a general answer I'd appreciate that. I see this answer for $n=2$, is there a known generalization?

By $\varphi\in H^n(G,U(1))$, do you mean a cocycle or a cohomology class?

And by $U(1)$, do you mean ${z\in {\mathbb C}^*\ |\ z\bar z=1}$ ?

@Mikhail Borovoi might have been a slight abuse of notation. I mean that $\varphi$ is a cocycle, belonging to some unknown cohomology class $[\varphi]$. Added a small edit, hope it clarifies.
For the second Q, yes, with the usual group action (I guess the question makes sense for any $G$-module)

My memory is that the Handbook of Computational Group Theory suggests that one can restrict to a generating set in one of the variables of the cocycle, but otherwise needs to know all the values for the other input.

You can also restrict to values from a $p$-Sylow subgroup to determine the $p$-local part of the cohomology class, by Cartan-Eilenbergs stable element formula (and do this for every $p$ to fully determine it).
